# Identify a mystery movie about foreknowledge of memory loss

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to remember this movie.  Hopefully someone can help me out.

There's this guy who had severe memory loss, but somehow he knew it was going to happen ahead of time, and he had planted clues for himself so he could go through and investigate and figure out, afterwards, what it was that had happened that led to him losing his memory.  I think it was related to something he had been working on that was too secret for even the employees to know about, but I'm not sure.

(And before anyone says "Memento," it's not Memento.)  Sorry I don't have much more to go by.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sounds like [Paycheck](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paycheck_%28film%29).

> Ben Affleck plays an engineer who is hired to work on a top-secret project with the understanding that his memory will be erased after he completes the job. He completes the job, and he gives up millions of dollars to receive an envelope, which contains several items such as a key, a pack of cigarettes, sunglasses, a bullet, etc. Ben uses these items to regain his memory while his old employer is trying to kill him, and the government is trying to put him in jail for something he doesn't remember doing. Every item plays a part in saving his life, his memory, and our future.

Comment: And here I was going to go with Clean Slate http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109443/